# hdvp html player v1.0 doesn't work in firefox browser

Tags: video-player

Downloaded ubuntu 21.04 and cannot play videos in browser. Adobe flash player needed in Firefox browser. Since Adobe Flash is EOL after end of 2020, can I use some other flash sw? Any advice?

Comment: There is no such version of Ubuntu as 21.4

Comment: And apparently neither "hdvp html player". This question needs a serious edit in order to be answerable.

Comment: Ok David, you got me, missed 0. It is Ubuntu 21.04